# How to output a float product of int multipliers?

Tags: c, type-conversion, printf

I am trying to calculate the exponent of a number. When I do everything as int I get the correct result, but the output must be float, when I try to convert with %f in printf() I get 0, when I use %d I get the correct result. I cannot change the main() portion of the program, I can only alter the *powerArgs() function. The program input is 3, 5.

Full disclosure, this is part of a school assignment. I am not asking for complete code. I would appreciate a more general answer showing me what I am forgetting, possibly what area I should study more to find the answer myself.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int *powerArgs(int *pA, int *pB);

/* MAIN */
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    if (argc != 3)
    {
       printf("?Invalid number of arguments\n");
       system("pause");
       exit(1);
    }

    int parmA = atoi(argv[1]);
    int parmB = atoi(argv[2]);
    int idx;

/* Part C: Raise parmA to the power of parmB.  Return pointer to the result */    
/*         Reset the original values after we print the result */
    printf("%d raised to the %d power is %0.1f\n", parmA, parmB, *powerArgs(&parmA, &parmB));

    printf("\n");  

    system("pause");
    exit(0);
}

int *powerArgs(int *pA, int *pB)
{
      int idx, result = *pA;

      for (idx = 1; idx < *pB; idx++)
      {
          result *= *pA;
      }

      return &result;
}
```

Comment: No, no, no. You can't return a *pointer* to `result` from `powerArgs`. `result` is a *local variable* in that function. It doesn't exist once the function exits. You must return an int (or float) *value*.

Comment: I actually have a different comment: do not, even in homework, name anything parmA, parmB, or variants thereof.  Instead, name your variables base and exponent.  People reading your code later (you included) will find it much easier to read if they don't have to keep looking to see whether parmA was the base or the exponent and to see that you didn't at some point swap them.

Comment: I did not write the part with parmA and parmB. The portion main() was given by the teacher, and we must write the called function to return the expect result outputed as show. That's why I can't just output as int. But I appreciate the point, I usually have more descriptive variable names, such as interation, base, product.

Comment: One of the biggest problems in programming design today is crappy interfaces.  This is a *great* example of one.  There is absolutely no reason (no, not even performance) to take references or pointers as inputs, and even worse, return a pointer.  All it does is make the code more complicated than it needs to be.  Bugs hide in complexity.

Comment: @mcabral: ["The homework tag...is now discouraged,"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10812) but, @cyotee, please (as always) follow [general guidelines](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints): state any special restrictions, show what you've tried so far, and ask about what specifically is confusing you.  (You did a good job of that here.)

Comment: @Roger Pate that's not the official SO position. i'm not changing it back again so we drop the issue, but you should not continue retagging until there's an official position. anyways, this still is homework, as the OP states it.

Comment: @mcabral: There is no position from Jeff — I link to the source of my quote, which includes advice for cyotee and answerers — and I'm not saying this isn't homework.  If the community had to wait for Jeff before every little thing, we'd get nothing done.  We don't tag [plz-only-code] or [paid-work] or [hobbyist], so why tag [homework-appropriate-responses-only]?  *Whose* homework guidelines are in effect for that tag, yours, mine, or cyotee's?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`float` and `int` convert automatically in C - you can assign either one to the other, and the only thing to watch out for is that if you assign too large a float to an int, then you get undefined behavior (or possibly an unspecified result, I forget. Either way it's not good).

So, your `powerArgs` function can just be:

```
float powerArgs(float a, int b) {
    // do some stuff and return a value
}
```

Then you can call it as `powerArgs(parmA, parmB)`, even though `parmA` is an int.

Edit: if you can't change the call parameters, you can do this instead

```
float powerArgs(int *a, int *b) {
    float base = *a;
    int exponent = *b;
    ...
}
```

If your professor has really set you code where the function is called as `*powerArgs(int *a, int *b)`, then your professor is a menace. There is no earthly reason why an exponentiation function should return a *pointer* to a float. There's an ugly workaround you could use:

```
float *powerArgs(int *a, int *b) {
    static float result;
    ...
    result = /* the result of the calculation */;
    return &result;
}
```

The problem with this is, all calls to `powerArgs` share the same object `result`. `static` stops it from ceasing to exist at the end of the call, but the sharing will introduce problems in the long run. It is *not* good practice to do this, but it might be the best solution to the problem you've been set.

C++ sneaky solution:

```
struct FloatWrapper {
    float value;
    float operator*() {
        return value;
    }
    FloatWrapper(float f) : value(f) {}
};

FloatWrapper powerArgs(int *a, int *b) {
    ...
    float result = /* whatever */;
    ...
    return result;
}
```

This returns an object of class FloatWrapper, by value, and FloatWrapper overloads the `*` operator. This means that `*powerArgs(...)` evaluates to the float that the function should have returned by value in the first place, *without* needing a pointer to any special storage place.

By the way, you might want to check what your function does when `parmB` is 0.

Comment: Thank you so much. I see that I was handling the type-conversion at the wrong time. Your examples show the different ways I could handle it successfully. And thank you for not just recommending that I change the function call, as I can't.

Comment: @cyotee: if you're at all interested, I've just thought of a C++ solution that would allow the call as `*powerArgs`, without any shared data, and also without leaking memory. I'll post it, but if you're only learning C, not C++, just ignore it...

Answer (score 1):

First, your `int *powerArgs(int *pA, int *pB)` function returns the address of a local variable, which results in undefined behavior. Use the following instead:

```
int powerArgs(int *pA, int *pB)
{
  int idx, result = *pA;

  for (idx = 1; idx < *pB; idx++)
  {
      result *= *pA;
  }

  return result;
}
```

Next, if you want to convert to `float`, you shouldn't do that in the call to `printf()`, but rather convert the value to `float` *before* the call like so:

```
printf("%d raised to the %d power is %0.1f\n", parmA, parmB, (float)powerArgs(&parmA, &parmB));
```

Comment: ITYM `(float) powerArgs(&parmA, &parmB);`

Comment: Thank you for the help. That does clarify my understanding of how to do this properly. But the assignment says we can't edit main(). We can only build the function to produce the desired output based on how it is called. I wish I could just rewrite to make it more sensible, but I can't.

Answer (score 1):

When a function terminates, all its local variables cease to exist (and their addresses point to garbage). To please your teacher who came up with that very awkward interface, you have to find a way to keep an object alive after the function exists.

You have, at least, 3 options:
a) reuse one of the input parameters
b) use a global variable
c) use a static variable

option a)

```
int *powerArgs(int *pA, int *pB) {
    /* calculate */
    *pA = CALCULATED_VALUE;
    return pA;
}
```

option b)

```
int global_power;

int *powerArgs(int *pA, int *pB) {
    /* calculate */
    global_power = CALCULATED_VALUE;
    return &global_power;
}
```

option c)

```
int *powerArgs(int *pA, int *pB) {
    static int static_power;
    /* calculate */
    static_power = CALCULATED_VALUE;
    return &static_power;
}
```

Neither of these "solutions" is good; the least bad is option c)